# Removing "src" folder from project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Default structure of Gradle project created by IntelliJ IDEA is:

```
module/src/main/java
module/src/main/resources
module/src/test/java
module/src/test/resources
```

I would like to cut `src` folder, so I will be left with:

```
module/main/java
module/main/resources
module/test/java
module/test/resources
```

I have been removing them from every possible corner in project structure -> modules. Removed them by clicking on them from IJ, but IJ keeps creating them. I have even replaced all strings in whole project folder `"/src"` to `""` but it works until next Gradle refresh + rebuild.

How to get rid of that folder?

Comment: I don't know gradle, but src/main/ is just a convention in maven which you can redefine. I'm pretty sure it's the same in gradle (and that redefinition should be picked by Intelij)

Comment: begs the question of WHY you want to go against an industry standard project structure?

Comment: I already have too much folders/files, and this particular folder does not serve any meaningful purpose, or at least I do not understand this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change default project layout and remove `src` folder from it's paths, by changing source sets properties as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['main/resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['test/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

You can read about it in the [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:changing_java_project_layout).

Comment: Yes, I have done it too. It correctly flags those dirs as sources/tests, however still recognizes (and recreated) old ones.

Comment: That's odd and seems to be IDE specific... Have you tried to modify `Context root` property for every source set in every module's configuration (within Idea's project structure properties)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have removed every with "src" and created new same, but without "src", then marked directories as source and resources by hand. But after Gradle refresh and rebuild, it reverts all settings. It does not matter, if I edit it through IDE or with notepad in .idea folder - same effect.

Comment: @spam Have you actually removed them from the filesystem? Removing them from Intellij doesn't necessary delete them on the file system.

Comment: Yes, I have removed them  from filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of of neither 'main' or 'test' source sets. Only thing you can do is mark them as excluded.

Comment: I do not want to get rid of "main" and "test". I want to get rid of "src" middleman folder.

Comment: Right, his code works for me too. The problem is, it still does not prevent IJ from recreating old ones, however indeed new ones works.